# Filtering through string for specific characters

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python and want to filter through a string for numbers and special characters at the moment what I'm using prints out Yes(for if there are numbers or special characters) and No(for if there are no such characters)
Here's what i use at the moment:

```
name_letters="123456789/*-.,`~<>?\:;!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]"
name= '123456'
def check_letters (text,char):

    count= 0
    for char in name:
     let= text[count]
     if name_letters== let:
        print('Yes')
     else:
        print("No")
     count+=1

for char in name_letters:
    check_letters(name,name_letters)
```

The problems that occur are:

1. After playing around with the variables it always just returns either Yes or No not a variation of the two
2. This not a huge problem but the loop runs longer than it needs to

Comment: `==` is the "equal to" operator. So in your case in the first loop you are comparing  `123456789/*-.,``~<>?\:;!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[] == 1`. With obviously doesn't match because it isn't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *filter* is not the word you're looking for, but more of a check if it exists. So you can use the [built-in any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function to see if any character will match inside of the string.

Using the in operator, you can check if a single character exists within the string:

```
'$' in string       # found
'$' not in string   # not found
```

A pythonic way to handle this in your code would look something like this:

```
#Returns boolean True/False if any character exists in string
def check_letters(string, characters):
    charset = set(characters)
    return any((c in charset) for c in string)

print "Yes" if check_letters(name, name_letters) else "No"
```